# Where to record existing assets when starting double-entry accounting

Tags: loans, accounting, assets, double-entry, liabilities

Very rarely would anyone start recording their accounting with zero assets or liabilities. Question is - under which account would you record them? Specifically, if you own property, you would debit `Assets - Property`, but what would you credit? (I'm assuming not cash, since the actual transaction would have happened some time ago).

Similarly, if you have an outstanding liability (say, a loan), you would credit your `Liabilities` account, but what would you debit?

Would an account like "Beginning Balances" make sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would credit the `Equity` account, for both (negative for a loan, obviously). `Beginning balance` account should be one of your `Equity` accounts.

You do that with the **basis** value (current), not the current market value. This is exactly for the reason of [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/27849/asset-sale-net-proceeds-to-cash-and-capital-gains) - to account for gains when realized.